# read key value from xml using powershell

Tags: powershell, security, xml-parsing, github-actions, key-value

I wish to read the below xml values for a given key in a secure encrypted manner using powershell.

So, for example, a given key `port` it should print the value `8814`

Likewise for `app_name` it should print `Signup-qa`

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>

<parameters>

<setParameter value="Signup-qa" name="app_name"/>
<setParameter value="8814" name="port"/>
<setParameter value="true" name="debug"/>

</parameters>
```

I tried the below but I get error.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powershell # [xml]$xml=Get-Content C:\AMD\setparam.xml

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powershell $xml.SelectSingleNode('//entry[@name="app_name"]').Value
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $xml.SelectSingleNode('//entry[@name=app_name]').Value
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Also, wanted to know if this is a secure way [encrypted] to read the key-value?

I will eventually take this to a github actions workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)) calls are separate, unrelated sessions, so you cannot create state (define the `$xml` variable) in one call and expect another to see it.

Instead, use a *single* call, and let [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Xml) read and query your file directly:

```bash
powershell -c "(Select-Xml -Literalpath C:\AMD\setparam.xml '//setParameter[@name=\"app_name\"]').Node.Value"
```

Note:

- As shown, your sample XML isn't valid, because the [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) (`[xml]`) class apparently requires `"yes"` - not `"true"` - as the `standalone` attribute value.
- Also, in the XPath query above I've replaced `entry` with `setParameter` to match your sample XML.
- For robustness, the entire `-c` (`-Command`) argument (parameter `-Command` is *implied* if you omit it)<sup>[1]</sup> is enclosed in `"..."`, which isn't strictly necessary in this case; however, you *do* need to escape the `"` that are part of the PowerShell command either way, as `\"`

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, now defaults to `-File`.</sup>

Comment: you were right. Removed the blank spaces at the beginning of the file and it worked.

Comment: will your solution simply work if the XML is on a shared network drive? say `\\remotehost\D$\files/setparam.xml` ?

Comment: @Ashar, it should, yes.